# Check for input being an integer

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation, integer, inputbox

I am aware that there are quite a few questions around on here regarding this, but none of the answers seem to work for me. I'm trying to make my program check to see if the given input is a 1 or a 0 and i really have hit a dead end. I'm still new to programming and the internet has helped load when it comes to this but i cant find anything

this program is a thingy I'm doing for my coursework, the bitty im trying to get this on is as follows

```
Public Class Form1
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Sensor1, Sensor2, Sensor3, SensorTotal, Temp As Integer

    Sensor1 = InputBox("Please enter the state of Sensor 1, 0 for off, 1 for on", "System")
    If Sensor1 = 1 Then PictureBox5.Hide()

    Sensor2 = InputBox("Please enter the state of Sensor 2, 0 for off, 1 for on", "System")
    If Sensor2 = 1 Then PictureBox6.Hide()

    Sensor3 = InputBox("Please enter the state of Sensor 3, 0 for off, 1 for on", "System")
    If Sensor3 = 1 Then PictureBox7.Hide()
```

I need to detect if the input from each sensor is being given as a 1 or a 0 from the input box. a dead end has been hit and i cannot progress any further on this program until i work out/ find a way yo get this done.

It needs to check if the given value is a 1 or a 0 given as an integer, if its not a 1 or a 0 it needs to ask again and keep asking until a 1 or a 0 is given

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: You have lots of type conversion going on there that you are not even aware about - you need to switch `option strict on`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the exception i got was systeminvalidcastexception because i was giving it values it could not accept :P but thanks to the people below i have got it sorted

Comment: @MattWilko I don't even know what that is so i don't know how it would or wouldn't help, i have visual studio set up the way my college has it set up on all the computers here

Comment: Please remember to upvotes and accept an answer if one has helped you. you should look up Option Strict to learn a bit more about it as switching it on will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Int32.TryParse` and following loops:

```
Dim Sensor1, Sensor2, Sensor3, SensorTotal, Temp As Integer
Dim sensor1Valid, sensor2Valid, sensor3Valid As Boolean
Dim validSensorValues = {0, 1}

While Not sensor1Valid
    Dim s1 As String = InputBox("Please enter the state of Sensor 1, 0 for off, 1 for on", "System")
    sensor1Valid = Int32.TryParse(s1, Sensor1) AndAlso validSensorValues.Contains(Sensor1)
End While
If Sensor1 = 1 Then PictureBox5.Hide()

While Not sensor2Valid
    Dim s2 As String = InputBox("Please enter the state of Sensor 2, 0 for off, 1 for on", "System")
    sensor2Valid = Int32.TryParse(s2, Sensor2) AndAlso validSensorValues.Contains(Sensor2)
End While
If Sensor2 = 1 Then PictureBox6.Hide()

While Not sensor3Valid
    Dim s3 As String = InputBox("Please enter the state of Sensor 3, 0 for off, 1 for on", "System")
    sensor3Valid = Int32.TryParse(s3, Sensor3) AndAlso validSensorValues.Contains(Sensor3)
End While
If Sensor3 = 1 Then PictureBox7.Hide()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Integer.TryParse` - it is probably best to put this all in a separate function:

```
Public Function GetInputState(sensorNum as Integer) As Integer
    Dim inputValue as Integer = -1
    Do 
        Dim inputString = InputBox("Please enter the state of Sensor " & sensorNum &  ", 0 for off, 1 for on", "System")
        If Not Int32.TryParse(inputString, inputValue) then inputValue = -1
    Loop Until inputValue = 1 OrElse InputValue = 0
    Return inputValue
End Function
```

Int32.TryParse return True if the Parse succeeded, so if the parse fails it sets the value to -1 to ensure that it goes round the loop again and asks for a number. If the parse succeeds it checks the value is either zero or 1.

Then you can be sure that the value entered is 1 or 0 like this:

```
Sensor1 = GetInputState(1)
Sensor2 = GetInputState(2)
Sensor3 = GetInputState(3)
```